# Consequences of Adjusting AllowedVideoLag in Flash Media Server

Tags: flash-media-server

Our site allows users to record videos using their webcams.  This video is saved by FMS 3.5 on the server and then processed.  But some users with low bandwidth end up having videos where the video freezes and audio continues playing.  From my research, it looks like setting the  setting on the FMS server to a higher number will help with this.

The default value is 5.  Before I go and make this value much higher, I'd like to know the potential impact to the server.  Obviously increasing the value will increase resource usage, but what resources?  Will the buffer be stored in memory, or on disk?